# AWS CodeDeploy - Error deploying - ApplicationDoesNotExistException

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to deploy a project in AWS using :

```
$ aws --region eu-central-1 deploy push --application-name DemoApp --s3-location s3://paquirrin-codedeploy/Project1.zip --ignore-hidden-file --source .
```

But I got this error:

```
A client error (ApplicationDoesNotExistException) occurred when calling the RegisterApplicationRevision operation: Applications not found for 289558260222
```

but the application exists:

```
$ aws deploy list-applications
{
    "applications": [
        "DemoApp"
    ]
}
```

and CodeDeploy agent is running

```
[root@ip-171-33-54-212 ~]# /etc/init.d/codedeploy-agent status
The AWS CodeDeploy agent is running as PID 2649
```

but I haven't found the folder `deployment-root` inside `/opt/codedeploy-agent` !

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 12):

You are deploying to region `eu-central-1`. But you may not be listing the applications in `eu-central-1` using following command:

```
aws deploy list-applications
```

Instead, use following command to ensure that application exists:

```
aws deploy list-applications --region eu-central-1
```